# Div não mostra imagem

Tags: css, html

Estou aprendendo a criar sites agora e estou com problemas para inserir imagem pelo css. Quando uso a tag ;img src="imagem.jpg", no arquivo .html a imagem aparece, porém se eu coloco no arquivo .css e passo para div, não tem nenhum sinal dela.

Preciso de ajuda não sei o que está errado

Aqui está meu codigo html e css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>RSU</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" type="text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="top"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
.top {
    background-image: url('../imagens/caverna1920.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 500;
    height: 500;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código CSS está incorreto.

1. Está faltando o `px` ou `%` ao definir altura e largura.
2. O `background-image` aceita apenas a imagem, para utilizar a imagem e a opção`no-repeat`, utilize apenas `background`

O correto é:

```
.top {
    background: url('../imagens/caverna1920.jpg') no-repeat center;
    width: 500px; /* ou 500% */
    height: 500px; /* ou 500% */
}
```

Comment: Mesmo adicionando % ou px não funciona, antes tinha colocado background-size: cover; e também não funcionou

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Adicionei mais um erro que verifiquei agora.

Comment: É isso mesmo obrigado ae

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro está em usar `background-image` com parâmetros (ex. `no-repeat`).

Para usar parâmetros na imagem de fundo, utilize apenas `background`. Ex.:

```
background: url('../imagens/caverna1920.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Outra coisa é especificar `px` nas dimensões. Sem `px` (ou qualquer outro indicador), o CSS não reconhece o valor.

```
.top {
    background: url('../imagens/caverna1920.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Você pode, inclusive, incluir uma cor de fundo ao mesmo tempo que uma imagem:

```
background: red url('https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Comment: É isso msm valew